Dynamic Google Sheet Task
I have a Google Sheet that collects data from a source sheet using the filter or (query in some cases) function in ascending order of dates of entry. The sheet is available to other team members, who then input additional information in the corresponding rows of each item.
However, if a new entry that was omitted ab initio is entered in between existing entries in the source sheet, it reflects on the target sheet. This causes the information entered in the corresponding cells to misalign.
How can I resolve this issue? How can I make sure that the new entry does not assume the information entered for other rows when it gets to the target sheet? How can I ensure that the data entered by team members moves with its original source data and does not remain static?
Currently, I have to copy the rows down to align with the data import from the source sheet when a new entry is inserted.
Please see the example in this sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_K2777Idh-uy3Om3x3VVX6i1eso5OX67wL22VgkgKto/edit?gid=0#gid=0
I queried the data from Sheet 1 into Sheet 2. I inserted a new entry, James John, in sheet 1, which reflected in sheet 2, as expected. However, James John inherited the location originally meant for Valda Powell.
How can I make Valda Powell's location move with Valda while the row above remains empty? How can I bind North to Valda Powell in Sheet 2 despite the change?

In order to get help with this, you need to post the code you are talking about in text form to the question so someone can take a look.

@easilyfixed I just posted a sample data scenario

https://support.google.com/docs/thread/95901649

Links to external data are not the same thing as posting the code to the question.  That being said @z.. seems to have found your answer.  Read up there and good luck.

Were you able to successfully implement what you wanted from the previous comment? If not yet, kindly give public access to your Google Sheet.

@Saddles Apologies, access has been updated. Thanks a lot

In the example spreadsheet you provided, you'll need to create a new column on both sheets, which would look like this:
Sheet1

Sheet2


Note: You may use other labels in column A as long as they're unique and the same on both sheets since the data of each row would be associated with it.

Afterwards, this is the formula that you may use on B1 of Sheet2:
={"Date", "Client", "Client ID"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A = "", "", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, Sheet1!A2:D, {2,3,4}, 0), "No entry at this index number")))}

This is what it would look like:

Even if new entries are added in between the cells of Sheet1, it won't affect what shows up on Sheet2 right away since an Index Number needs to be assigned from column A to it.

Credit goes to @z.. for providing Solving the Dynamic / Static Data Alignment challenge using Alignment Index Numbers created by Lance.NYC, one of Google's Product Experts.

thanks a lot for the input. Will try it out.
